# Is it possible to change a signed byte to an int in compiled assembly code?

Tags: assembly, patching

I'm trying to mess around with an old game and I want to reposition a UI element.

I found the address of where the x and y position get set (It's set to an X position of 90 and a Y position of 358) but it appears that because the 90 value is less than 128, the compiler optimized the assembly and changed the assembly from a push int (68 ? ? ? ?) to a push signed byte (6a ?).

This means that I'm unable to extend the X position beyond 128.

Is there any way for me to set the X position to something like 1000? I would need to somehow be able to change the assembly code to do a push int instead, correct? Will asm help me achieve that? Or what other methods could I use?

Here's what I'm talking:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, 0x6a is the instruction `push Ib`, in this case, the operand is encoded in only one byte and it's signed (i.e. 0x6a 0xff → push -1). You need to promote to the instruction 0x68 `push Iz` which means expand the instruction. Your choice is rather limited. I suggest you try to find some `code cave` and jump on it to setup the stack as you want.

To do so:

- the first part is to find some free executable space. You might find that at the end of the `.text` section. Because of the alignment, you'll find some unused space padded with `nop`.
- Once you find one, patch these pushes with a `jmp` to this location.
- In this free space, you can freely encode your 0x68 pushes.
- Finally, encode another `jmp` from this free space to jump back to the initial point.